# how to print nothing when "Tests-on: " has no digit

Tags: python

I have the following code which checks for string "Testson-on: " in variable comments and gets the latest value based on dep[-1].split,it is generally expected
that "Testson: " will be appended with digits ( please see example below),now I have a case where there are instances where there is no digit after "Tests-on: ",how do I change the code to incorporate this case and 
dep[-1].split should print nothing....

```
With digit:Tests-on: 12345

Without digit:Tests-on:
```

CODE:-

```
dep = re.findall(r'(?<=Tests-on:\s)[\d]+(?=\n)', comments)
print "findexternaldep : dep"
print dep
if dep:
    deps = dep[-1].split()
print deps
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the digits optional,

```
reg = re.compile("\bTests-on:\s*(\d*)", re.I | re.M)
```

then check the result

```
for test_on in reg.findall(s):
    if test_on:
        print(test_on)
        num = int(test_on)
    else:
        num = None
```

Comment: what is s in reg.findall(s) ?

Comment: @user3131197 the string you are searching through - `comments`, in your code.